# Executing a shell script with arguments from a python script

Tags: python, shell

My Shell script is executed like this from the command line

```
./pro.sh "Argument1"
```

I am calling it from my python script currently like this

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split('bash pro.sh "Argument1"'))
```

How do I pass the value of Argument1 as a variable. My argument to the script can be any string. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
subprocess.Popen(["bash", "pro.sh", "Argument1"])
```

If your string argument is multiple words, it should work fine.

```
subprocess.Popen(["bash", "pro.sh", "Argument with multiple words"])
```

As long as the multiple words are in one string in the list passed to `subprocess.Popen()`, it is considered one argument in the argument list for the command.

You should not use `shell=True` unless you have a good reason. It can be a security problem if you aren't very careful how it is used.

Answer (score 4):

use subprocess to call your shell script

```
subprocess.Popen(['run.sh %s %s' % (var1, var2)], shell = True)
```

Comment: My argument is a string of multiple words. When I use this, only the first word of the string is being used.

Comment: U have to store the string in variable var1,var2 and then execute the script

Comment: I have already done that. It reads only the first word of var1. var 1 contains multiple words

Comment: Ohk,then it that case use subprocess.Popen(["bash", ".sh file", "Multiple Arguments"])